# toAncestor predicate in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, ancestor

Example 1st:

predicate:

```
belongs(X,[X|_]).
belongs(X,[_|Ytail]):-belongs(X,Ytail).
```

Check:

`belongs(a,[x,c,a,b]).`

Recursion:

1st step:

```
belongs(a,[c,a,b]).
```

2nd step

```
belongs(a,[a,b]).
```

returns true and here SWI-Prolog ends

It cuts the head. In the 1st step cuts x, then cuts c, and when a is in the first place in this list [a,b] the head a is the same as the head of list [a,b]. a=a.

Example 2nd

```
parent(d,c).
parent(c,b).
parent(b,a).
```

The below is fine and I understand it. It writes X (head) then -> sign and then parent of the X.

```
toAncestor(A,A):-write(A).
toAncestor(X,Y):-write(X),write('->'),parent(A,X),toAncestor(A,Y).
```

Recursion:

Check:

```
?- toAncestor(a,d).
a->b->c->d
true ;
d->
false.

?- toAncestor(X,Y).
_4644
X = Y ;
_4644->d
X = c,
Y = d ;
d->c
X = b,
Y = c ;
c->d
X = b,
Y = d ;
d->b
X = a,
Y = b ;
b->c
X = a,
Y = c ;
c->d
X = a,
Y = d ;
d->
false.

?- trace,toAncestor(a,d).
   Call: (9) toAncestor(a, d) ? creep
   Call: (10) write(a) ? creep
a
   Exit: (10) write(a) ? creep
   Call: (10) write(->) ? creep
->
   Exit: (10) write(->) ? creep
   Call: (10) parent(_4916, a) ? creep
   Exit: (10) parent(b, a) ? creep
   Call: (10) toAncestor(b, d) ? creep
   Call: (11) write(b) ? creep
b
   Exit: (11) write(b) ? creep
   Call: (11) write(->) ? creep
->
   Exit: (11) write(->) ? creep
   Call: (11) parent(_4916, b) ? creep
   Exit: (11) parent(c, b) ? creep
   Call: (11) toAncestor(c, d) ? creep
   Call: (12) write(c) ? creep
c
   Exit: (12) write(c) ? creep
   Call: (12) write(->) ? creep
->
   Exit: (12) write(->) ? creep
   Call: (12) parent(_4916, c) ? creep
   Exit: (12) parent(d, c) ? creep
   Call: (12) toAncestor(d, d) ? creep
   Call: (13) write(d) ? creep
d
   Exit: (13) write(d) ? creep
   Exit: (12) toAncestor(d, d) ? creep
   Exit: (11) toAncestor(c, d) ? creep
   Exit: (10) toAncestor(b, d) ? creep
   Exit: (9) toAncestor(a, d) ? creep
true .
```

When I type:

```
gtrace,toAncestor(a,d).
```

it shows:

1st transition

```
X=a
Y=d
A=b

write(X),write('->'),parent(b,a),toAncestor(b,d)
```

it saves b and sets as X

2nd transition

```
X=b
Y=d
A=c

write(X),write('->'),parent(c,b),toAncestor(c,d)
```

it saves c and sets as X

3rd transition

```
X=c
Y=d
Y=A=d

write(X),write('->'),parent(d,c),toAncestor(d,d)
```

it saves d and sets as X

4th transition

```
X=d
Y=A=d

write(X),write('->'),toAncestor(d,d)
```

because

Basis of the recursion says:

```
toAncestor(A,A):-write(A).
```

Here ends, returns true and exit.

```
fromAncestor(A,A):-write(A).
fromAncestor(X,Y):-parent(A,X),fromAncestor(A,Y),write('->'),write(X).

fromAncestor(a,d).
d->c->b->a
true;

?- trace,fromAncestor(a,d).
   Call: (9) fromAncestor(a, d) ? creep
   Call: (10) parent(_5108, a) ? creep
   Exit: (10) parent(b, a) ? creep
   Call: (10) fromAncestor(b, d) ? creep
   Call: (11) parent(_5108, b) ? creep
   Exit: (11) parent(c, b) ? creep
   Call: (11) fromAncestor(c, d) ? creep
   Call: (12) parent(_5108, c) ? creep
   Exit: (12) parent(d, c) ? creep
   Call: (12) fromAncestor(d, d) ? creep
   Call: (13) write(d) ? creep
d
   Exit: (13) write(d) ? creep
   Exit: (12) fromAncestor(d, d) ? creep
   Call: (12) write(->) ? creep
->
   Exit: (12) write(->) ? creep
   Call: (12) write(c) ? creep
c
   Exit: (12) write(c) ? creep
   Exit: (11) fromAncestor(c, d) ? creep
   Call: (11) write(->) ? creep
->
   Exit: (11) write(->) ? creep
   Call: (11) write(b) ? creep
b
   Exit: (11) write(b) ? creep
   Exit: (10) fromAncestor(b, d) ? creep
   Call: (10) write(->) ? creep
->
   Exit: (10) write(->) ? creep
   Call: (10) write(a) ? creep
a
   Exit: (10) write(a) ? creep
   Exit: (9) fromAncestor(a, d) ? creep
true .
```

Prolog checks in the beginning if the each target has been met. Let me explain with simple example.

Imagine tree where c is on the top and it is a parent of b and a.

We will write this tree as:

```
parent(c,a)
parent(c,b)
theSameParent(X,Y):-parent(A,X),parent(A,Y).
```

Predicate theSameParent(c,d) will not be processed because target 1 parent(A,X) cannot be fulfilled and Prolog does not even check the second target parent(A,Y).

So, in case fromAncestor(a,d). Prolog is checking if the targets are fulfilled before it will call write(X): parent(A,X) and fromAncestor(A,Y), if they are fulfilled it goes to next step and check once again. The last step is fromAncestor(d,d). Prolog does not check who is the parent of d, but stops, because the basis of recursion has been met: fromAncestor(A,A):-write(A).

So remember to learn:

```
(B)toAncestor(A,A):-write(A).
(R)toAncestor(X,Y):-write(X),write('->'),parent(A,X),toAncestor(A,Y).
(B)fromAncestor(A,A):-write(A).
(R)fromAncestor(X,Y):-parent(A,X),fromAncestor(A,Y),write('->'),write(X).
```

where (B) is basis of recursion and (R) is a recursion.

```
(B) (n+1)!=n!*(n+1)
(R) 0! =1
```

Example:

```
2!=1!*2=(0!*1)*2=(1*1)*2=2
```

because 0! = 1

Many thanks to lurker. You helped me a lot.

Comment: `toAncestor(A,Y):-parent(A,X).` makes no sense. `X` and `Y` are singleton.

Comment: `toAncestor(A,A):-write(A).`
`toAncestor(X,Y):-write(X),write('->'),parent(A,X),toAncestor(A,Y).`
are the correct predicates then.

check:
`toAncestor(a,i).`
show only a->

`toAncestor(A,A).`
shows: _5982->a->a->a->b->a->b->a->c->a->c->a->c->a->d->a->f->b->a->f->b->a->

`toAncestor(i,a).`
shows:
i->c->a

Can anyone explain this to me how the recursion works in for all three cases mentioned above?

Comment: If you need to add/update query results, please edit your question and put it there, properly formatted. Comments are not the place to do it. Did you try doing a `trace` to see what the code is doing? Just enter `trace.` then execute a simple query, like `toAncestr(i, a)`.

Comment: I did a trace. You can see the result above.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking when you ask "how it works".  But the recursive clause for `toAncestor(X,Y)`, if you read it says, *The ancestor chain from `X` to `Y` is the person `X` followed by the ancestor chain from `R` to Y` where `R` is the parent of `X`*.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A clue: use gtrace instead of trace.
Example:
gtrace,toAncestor(a,d).
It will show every single step and exactly which sign is which parent. It shows X, Y and R.